# Admin panel rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make an admin controller, it has following 3 views index, members(list of users) and commet(all the feedback from the user) for the following i made following actions in controllers

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @members = User.all
    @comment = Feedback.all
  end
  def member
    @members = User.all
  end
  def comment
    @comment = Feedback.all

  end
end
```

Now I want to make comment and member view such that the admin can delete or edit the feedback or user, now how should write the methods for that?, since all this is happening in the same page?

I did not know what to search for this problem. So I am posting it, it might be repeated